# Change 'got' message for rspec's composable matchers

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I've written a composable matcher called have_backtrace/error_with_backtrace, like so:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_backtrace do |expected_backtrace|
  match do |error|
    error.backtrace == expected_backtrace
  end

  failure_message do |error|
    "expected error to have backtrace #{expected_backtrace.inspect}, actually got #{error.backtrace.inspect}"
  end
end

RSpec::Matchers.alias_matcher :error_with_backtrace, :have_backtrace
```

Then I can use it like this:

```
callback = double('reject_callback').as_null_object

# Do some stuff which could call callback.call

expect(callback).to have_received(:call).with(error_with_backtrace(caller))
```

This works fine, however the error message isn't exactly what I want

```
expected: (error with backtrace "backtrace_line_1", "backtrace_line_2", ... )
got: (#<RuntimeError: RuntimeError>)
```

I would like the 'got' part to also say `(error with backtrace ...)`

Is there any way of accomplishing this?